# Laravel 4, unit tests, extra data returned

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel

bros. Got a strange behaviour. I'm writing tests for my Laravel 4 [ClosureTable](https://github.com/franzose/ClosureTable) package.

All tests create new `Entity` (or `Entitites`) for further use. For example, one of the first tests: `ClosureTableTestCase::testInsertSingle`. When I run it, I got this:

`Exception: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 table pages_closure has no column named 0 (SQL: insert into "pages_closure" ("ancestor", "depth", "descendant", "0", "1", "2") values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)) (Bindings: array (
  0 => '1',
  1 => '0',
  2 => '1',
  3 => '1',
  4 => '1',
  5 => '0',
))`

And `var_dump` says me the following:

```
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  array(6) {
    'ancestor' =>
    string(1) "1"
    [0] =>
    string(1) "1"
    'descendant' =>
    string(1) "1"
    [1] =>
    string(1) "1"
    'depth' =>
    string(1) "0"
    [2] =>
    string(1) "0"
  }
}
```

However when I create an Entity via web interface, all's fine!

Errors come from `DB::select($selectQuery);` call when I run tests via terminal. As you can see, I somehow got [0], [1], and [2] extra array keys. **However when I create an Entity via web interface, all's fine!**

Error is in this method that's run internally:

```
protected function performInsertNode($descendant, $ancestor)
{
    $table = $this->closure;
    $ak = static::ANCESTOR;
    $dk = static::DESCENDANT;
    $dpk = static::DEPTH;

    DB::transaction(function() use($table, $ak, $dk, $dpk, $descendant, $ancestor){
        $selectQuery = "
            SELECT tbl.{$ak} as {$ak}, {$descendant} as {$dk}, tbl.{$dpk}+1 as {$dpk}
            FROM {$table} AS tbl
            WHERE tbl.{$dk} = {$ancestor}
            UNION ALL
            SELECT {$descendant}, {$descendant}, 0
        ";

        $results = DB::select($selectQuery);
        array_walk($results, function(&$item){ $item = (array)$item; });

        var_dump($results);

        DB::table($table)->insert($results);
    });
}
```

Do you can point me out a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, seems like fetch setting from app/config/database.php is `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`, if is not that.. you can try to force the settings to get `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` before `DB::select` with:

```
Config::set('database.fetch', PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Thank you, master =) My solution of enabling testing packages (stolen from MongoDB driver for Laravel) was slightly misconfigured. In that damn option! =) It was `$app['config']['database.fetch'] = null;`. Now I set it to `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`. Works like a charm :)